# Is the protobuf compiler failing to produce a method for querying the presence of a message field?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protoc

When compiling a .proto file with syntax = "proto3", the compiler should generate a method to query the presence of a message field regardless, [see documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/field_presence/#presence-in-proto3-apis)

[Message field always explicit presence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIdTX.png)

For a field e.g. "optional int32 test = 1", after compiling the .proto file to C# code, the class contains a query-method "bool HasTest()". but, when the field is of type Singular message no query-method is generated.

1. I downloaded protoc from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v25.2)
2. A proto file called Hazzer.proto contains:

//----- Hazzer.proto Begin -----
syntax = "proto3";

```
message Payload
{
int32 pay = 1;
}

message Conveyor
{
Payload load = 1;
optional int32 sequence = 2;
}
```

//----- Hazzer.proto End-----

3. I compile Hazzer.proto (which resides in a folder called Proto):
   protoc.exe --csharp_out=./ProtocOutput ./Protos/Hazzer.proto

My understanding is that under the explicit presence discipline, there should be generated a query method. Hence, in Conveyor.cs I should find "bool HasSequence()" and "bool HasLoad()".

Only HasSequence() is generated.
What am I missing?

Comment: `load` isn't optional so why should there be a `HasLoad()`? It would always return true

Comment: Isn't the "HasXXX" method only added for optional fields?

Comment: What language are you using and what tooling? `protoc` is only for C++ but you used the `C#` tag. protoc won't generate C# classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, protoc supports codegen for multiple languages

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in proto3, *every* field is an optional field; `optional` in proto3 actually means "presence tracking", i.e. in the case of `sequence`, if it is *not* `optional`, then a value is sent exactly when the value is non-zero, and there is no way to tell "zero explicitly specified" from "default zero"; if it *is* `optional`, then a value is sent *if it has been explicitly assigned a value*, and thus you can distinguish that a zero was explicitly specified; this doesn't apply to messages (`Payload load`) because there is no such thing as a default for a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Has...` mechanism is only needed for primitives; in the case of *messages*, the fact that the message itself can be tested for `null` is used as the "has" test; i.e.

```cs
if (obj.Load is not null)
{
  // yay, it has a value; do something funky
}
```

(and yes, it *could* have used `int?` for `Sequence`, but: it doesn't)

Comment: @Mark, the documentation says "This table outlines whether presence is tracked for fields in proto3 APIs" (see my attached image in the original post). My understanding is that a tracked field will have a HasXXX() method. The table has clearly checked the lines for message field to be tracked. Doesn't a tracked field necessarily mean that it will have a corresponding query method, i.e. a HasXXX() method or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: @Jossi85 I think your understanding (your word) is wrong. Field presence here means that it must be possible to tell whether a field was explicitly assigned a value; it doesn't say *how* you can tell. With a message field, you can tell whether or not it has been explicitly assigned a value - and the how is: by checking whether it is null or not